# Octave: create a class variable then access it within class (in constructor)

Tags: class, oop, octave

Maybe it's a trivial question but I would like to know how to access a constant property within the class contructor or a class function in octave. Let's make an example:

```
classdef Example % < FatherClass
    
    % read-only protected properties
    properties (Constant=true, Access=protected)
        all_levels = {"A","B","C","D"};
    endproperties
    
    % protected properties
    properties(Access=protected)
        level = 'D';
        output = '.';
    endproperties

    methods(Access=public)
        function obj = Example (level,outputfilepath)

            if any(strcmp(all_levels,level))
                obj.level = level;
            else
                error ("possible levels are: A B C D");
            endif

            obj.output = outputfilepath

        endfunction

    endmethods
end
```

running this class example I receive the error:

```
error: 'all_levels' undefined near line 12, column 12
error: called from
    Example at line 12 column 13
```

So, I've tried something like

```
if any(strcmp(obj.all_levels,level))
     obj.level = level;
```

With the same result, also defining a getter:

```
methods (Static = true)
  function lvs = gel_levels()
     lvs = all_levels
  endfunction
endmethods

...

methods(Access=public)
  function obj = Example (obj,level,outputfilepath)
    all_levels = get_levels()
    % disp(all_levels)
    if any(strcmp(all_levels,level))
       obj.level = level;
    else
       error ("possible levels are: A B C D");
    endif
       obj.output = outputfilepath
  endfunction
endmethods
```

Sorry but I'm quite new to octave and I haven't found any example about this. What I'm trying to accomplish is a simple *class variable*

Comment: Please read the descriptions of both [tag:matlab] and [tag:octave]. They are **not** the same, thus please only use both tags when asking about the similarities/differences between the two. Using both tags could result in answers being incompatible to the other software, unnecessarily forcing answerers to check validity of their code in both programs.

Comment: thanks for the specification @Adriaan i thought that is this case their behaviour was the same

Comment: @Gam it is. Adriaan is simply being a bit overzealous here. Technically speaking, keywords like `endfunction` are not valid matlab syntax (which only supports `end` for everything), so matlab "wouldn't run this". Philosophically speaking, however, your code is totally valid matlab code; if you were to correct the "endxxxxx" stuff, this code is totally valid matlab code with identical behaviour, and the spirit of the question could have been addressed by members from either community. Effectively, if you want people not feeling their time is being wasted, don't use octave-specific keywords.

Comment: @Gam I hasten to add that the "philosophical" part above isn't always the case. While they do share a common subset, there _are_ some very real differences between the two languages on rare occasion. So if you're not interested in crossfunctional code, then it's important to use the right tag. There is no guarantee that identical code in octave will work identically in matlab and vice versa. But in general, if you stick to the common subset of both languages this is not a concern. Compatibility within the bounds of that common subset is one of the major goals of the octave project, after all.

Comment: You say “in constructor”. Did you change the name of the class for this Q, but not of the constructor? Otherwise you don’t have any constructors in your code.

Comment: @CrisLuengo my mistake, I missed to change the name for the Q. Going to change it, thank you

Comment: In that case I see no reason why `obj.all_levels` wouldn’t work. Maybe an issue with Octave? I use MATLAB, am not at all familiar with Octave’s implementation of classes.

Comment: I recommend you leave a comment below Tasos’ answer, explaining your mistake and why their answer doesn’t address your question. Tasos is the most likely user here to give you a good answer about Octave.

Comment: I just tried this in MATLAB, and `obj.all_levels` works just fine. @Tasos, it seems that Adriaan was right, this is an Octave-specific question!

Comment: @CrisLuengo interesting, thank you for spotting this! Highlighting an interesting and non-obvious difference between the two languages is all the more reason to include both tags, don't you think? I intend to edit the octave tag to make it more useful and remove this archaic/belligerent wording from it. Not unilaterally of course, I'll raise it with the community first somehow; but I'm getting very tired of seeing this knee-jerk reaction every time. I feel that 9 times out of 10 it feels like it causes more harm (to either community) than benefit.

Comment: @CrisLuengo ah, actually, I tried the updated example in octave with `obj.all_levels` instead of `all_levels`, and it works as expected in octave too. So perhaps this particular debugging permutation simply didn't make it to the list of attempts :)

Comment: Yeah: I think the main problem here is that Constant properties and Static methods are not visible by default inside a class's method code, either in Matlab or Octave, and must be qualified. `Example.all_levels` will work; `obj.all_levels` is basically the same (even for static/constant members! (modulo overriding in subclasses)); an unqualified `all_levels` is a reference to a local variable or a global function; not any class member. Same for packages: classes and functions in a package are not in scope for other class members without an explicit `import`.

Comment: Also, be aware: There _are_ relevant differences between Matlab and Octave here, esp. WRT OOP. Octave intends to fully mimic Matlab, and _syntactically_ accepts most valid Matlab OOP (classdef) code, but several of the features are unimplemented or incomplete. The further you get from base OOP functionality, the more they diverge. And in Octave, both `'...'` and `"..."` literals produce `char` arrays, but in Matlab, `"..."` double-quotes produce `string` arrays, which have different behavior, and would cause this code to bork.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is a bit confusing, as different attempts seem to be using different parts, but in general I think your problem is that you are not passing the object as a formal parameter in the method.

It is also not clear if you are trying to modify the object "in-place", or trying to generate a new one ... but in any case remember that modifying objects in place is not possible (unless inheriting from the 'handle' object). Therefore the typical thing you're supposed to do is: pass the object in as the first input as you're supposed to do with class method definitions, modify it, return it, and then when you're using this method in your calling workspace, capture this object (typically in a variable by the same name as the called object in the calling workspace) via assignment.

This works for me:

```
%% in Example.m
classdef Example

    % read-only protected properties
    properties( Constant=true, Access=protected )
        all_levels = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
    endproperties

    % protected properties
    properties( Access = protected )
        level  = 'D';
        output = '.';
    endproperties

    methods( Access = public )
        function obj = Logging( obj, level, outputfilepath )
            valid_level_choice = any( strcmp( obj.all_levels, level ) );

            if valid_level_choice,   obj.level = level;
            else,                    error( "possible levels are: A B C D" );
            endif

            obj.output = outputfilepath;
        endfunction

        function get_level( obj )
            fprintf( "The level is %s\n;", obj.level );
        endfunction

    endmethods
endclassdef
```

```
%% In your console session
E = Example();
E.get_level()
%> The level is D
E = E.Logging( 'A', './' );
E.get_level()
%> The level is A
```

**UPDATE**

Updated code given the revised question / comments.
This works for me in octave 7.1.0

```
%% in Example.m
classdef Example % < FatherClass

    % read-only protected properties
    properties (Constant=true, Access=protected)
        all_levels = {"A","B","C","D"};
    endproperties

    % protected properties
    properties(Access=protected)
        level = 'D';
        output = '.';
    endproperties

    methods(Access=public)
        % Constructor
        function obj = Example (level,outputfilepath)
            valid_choice = any(strcmp(obj.all_levels,level));
            if valid_choice, obj.level = level;
            else, error ("possible levels are: A B C D");
            endif
            obj.output = outputfilepath;
        endfunction
        % Remaining Methods
        function get_level( obj ), fprintf( "The level is %s\n", obj.level ); endfunction
        function change_all_levels( obj, C ), obj.all_levels = C; endfunction
    endmethods
end
```

```
%% octave session
octave:1> E = Example('A', '.');
octave:2> E.get_level()
%> The level is A
octave:3> E.change_all_levels( {'this', 'should', 'not', 'work' } );
%> error: subsasgn: cannot assign constant property: all_levels
%> error: called from
%>    change_all_levels at line 25 column 66
```

Comment: Thank you @Tasos, sorry for the confusing question. I also made a little mess forgetting to rename `Logging` in `Example` making it the class constructor. Edited that.
Your solution works enabling me to access the class property; In making the constructor it's legit not passing `obj` as the first argument right (as seen for the documentation examples)?
Anyway, I'm accepting your answer as I managed to make it works for me and maybe learned something new :)

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense as an example, hahah. I will update the answer with the proper constructor. Having said that, one of the items you said didn't work is the actual working solution for this. Perhaps you tried many things and thought you covered that particular combination but didn't in reality? (happens to me in adventure games all the time!).

Comment: @Gam Incidentally, this is in the latest octave, 7.1.0. If my updated example doesn't work for you, perhaps you're on a slightly older octave version? `classdef` functionality is fairly new in octave (see https://octave.org/doc/v7.1.0/classdef-Classes.html) and is continuously updated.

Comment: I think you could have intercepted the real problem. I was using an older version of octave; the other day I've tested your solution with the latest version without any hitches

Comment: @Gam good to hear; thanks for letting us know; it might be useful to future visitors with the same problem!

Comment: Weird edge case I just want to point out here: `obj.all_levels = C;` will error out. But if you did class-qualification like `Example.all_levels = C;` instead, then it will not error out, and instead auto-vivify a new struct in a local variable named `Example` with a field named `all_levels`, the Constant property in the `Example` class will be unmodified, and the new local `Example` variable will shadow the class. IMHO, this is a batshit behavior which can lead to hard-to-debug bugs, and folks using Constant properties in Matlab/Octave OOP should be aware of it.